# LINQ correspondente a SQL com cláusula LIKE 'XXX%'

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq

Estou usando a seguinte LINQ para retornar uma consulta:

```
.Where(c => c.Nome.Contains(nome)).OrderBy(c => c.Nome)
```

Porém se o nome for `Maria`, ele traz:

```
José Maria
Maria José
```

Como trazer organizada como se estivesse executando a consulta SQL? Assim:

```
WHERE nome LIKE 'MARIA%'
```

Comment: Veja se essa solução te ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/482282/213393

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O `LIKE` pode estar no início, no fim ou em qualquer lugar. Então a equivalência é esta:

- `LIKE XXX%` -> [`StartsWith()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#overloads)
- `LIKE %XXX` -> [`EndsWith()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.endswith?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#overloads)
- `LIKE %XXX%` -> [`Contains()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_String_Contains_System_String_)

Pela documentação vemos que o `Contains()` é até menos flexível. Se quiser fazer com insensibilidade de caixa, ou comparação de acordo com algum critério específico, tem que escrever um código auxiliar (`text.IndexOf("Maria", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0`).

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {     
        var pessoas = new List<Pessoa>() {
            new Pessoa() { Nome = "Maria José" },
            new Pessoa() { Nome= "José Maria"}, 
            new Pessoa() { Nome= "José Maria José"} 
        };
        WriteLine("Início");
        foreach (var pessoa in pessoas.Where(p => p.Nome.StartsWith("Maria")).OrderBy(p => p.Nome)) {
            WriteLine(pessoa.Nome);
        }
        WriteLine();
        WriteLine("Fim");
        foreach (var pessoa in pessoas.Where(p => p.Nome.EndsWith("Maria")).OrderBy(p => p.Nome)) {
            WriteLine(pessoa.Nome);
        }
        WriteLine();
        WriteLine("Qualquer lugar");
        foreach (var pessoa in pessoas.Where(p => p.Nome.Contains("Maria")).OrderBy(p => p.Nome)) {
            WriteLine(pessoa.Nome);
        }
    }
}

public class Pessoa {
    public string Nome;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/LdI9Id). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/S447FE). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/Like.cs).

Answer (score 8):

Você pode usar EndsWith (apenas nomes que terminam com Maria) ou StartsWith (começam com Maria).

```
var filtrados = usuarios.Where(c => c.Nome.EndsWith("Maria"))
                        .OrderBy(c => c.Nome)
                        .ToList();
```

Exemplo/Teste: https://dotnetfiddle.net/V6y4kv

Answer (score 0):

É possível utilizar também desta forma:

Semelhante ao Like%:

```
SqlMethods.Like(c.Nome, "Maria%")
```

Semelhante ao %Like:

```
SqlMethods.Like(c.Nome,"%Maria")
```

Semelhante ao %like%:

```
SqlMethods.Like(c.Nome,"%Maria%")
```

Este metodo utiliza a biblioteca: System.Data.Linq.SqlClient