# Forma de utilizar o LIKE do SQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Estou tentando montar uma string que faça um filtro para comparar apenas um pedaço de uma numeração. Tentei fazer um recurso e busquei diversas formas de se fazer e até o momento não consegui.

```
using (NFSeDataContext context = new NFSeDataContext(ConnNFSe))
            {
                context.Connection.Open();

                var _s = (from p in context.NFS_Parcelas
                          join q in context.NFBP_CONCILIACAO_BRASPAGs on p.NFPA_CD_UNIDADE equals q.NFBP_CD_UNIDADE
                          where 
                            _idUnidade == p.NFPA_CD_UNIDADE
                           & _dtCred == p.NFPA_DT_MOVIMENTO
                           & p.NFPA_TX_COMPLEMENTO.Contains(q.NFBP_TID)

                          select new
                          {
                              p.NFPA_CD_UNIDADE,
                              q.NFBP_DT_FLUXO_CAIXA,
                              q.NFBP_COD_AUTORIZACAO,
                              q.NFBP_TID,
                              q.NFBP_VL_BRUTO_TRANSACAO,
                              q.NFBP_VL_LIQUIDO_TRANSACAO,
                              p.NFPA_NR_PARCELA,
                              q.NFBP_BANDEIRA
                          }).Distinct().ToList();


                context.Connection.Close();
                grvConciliacaoBraspag.DataSource = _s;
                grvConciliacaoBraspag.DataBind();


            }
```

Neste código o q.NFBP_TID apresenta como por exemplo um trecho que representa o valor:

104349099700D67C2012

O p.NFPA_TX_COMPLEMENTO apresenta um um trecho que apresenta o valor:

VISA13010000104349099700D67C2012BP 1201

Se comparar os dois resultados:

->104349099700D67C2012<-

VISA13010000 ->104349099700D67C2012<- BP 1201

Tenho quase certeza que essa verificação do Contains que eu fiz está errada. Esse foi um dos exemplos de tentativa. Apenas postei o código para se ter uma noção da minha dúvida.

Comment: Veja [`string.StartsWith()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/baketfxw(v=vs.110).aspx) e [`string.EndsWith()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/2333wewz(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91933/101 Duplicata?

Comment: Acredito que sim @bigown

Comment: @jbueno Desculpe até não informar isso, que é de grande importância...É dentro de um linq. Tanto no start, end e contains ele dá um not supported exception.

Comment: @bigown, Eu visualizei esta situação e o meu problema e até dúvida é se funciona em linq. Me desculpe até por não falar, pois nas 3 situações (start, end ou contains) ele dá um not supported exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tente utilizar o [`SqlMethods.Like`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.like(v=vs.110).aspx) ao invés do contains.

```
SqlMethods.Like(p.NFPA_TX_COMPLEMENTO, "%" + q.NFBP_TID + "%")
```

Comment: Salvou meu dia camarada, obrigado! :D